# NSMutableArray Initialise Only Once

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsscrollview

I have a program that parses xml from the web service by storing items in NSMutableArray which is initialised as follows:

```
- (id)init {

    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have used ScrollView delegate to check when user hits the bottom of tableview, in which i am calling another page of the web service to load more items at the bottom of already fetched items.

But when the tableview is reloaded, it does not add new items at the bottom of already fetched ones, instead it only the new ones appears.

Before i can set insertrowsatindexpaths with animation, i believe NSMutableArray is getting initialised again that is making the old entries disappear and showing the new ones only. How i can make the NSMutableArray initialise only once so when it gets the new entries, it loads them after the already fetched ones in the mutable array.

**EDIT**

According to the comments, looks like i am doing fine with the MutableArray and its getting initialised only once. Then there must be something wrong with the data source.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[channelFeed items] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ItemsViewCell *cell = (ItemsViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ItemsViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }

    FeedItem *item = [[channelFeed items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    cell.titleLabel.text = [item title];
    cell.pubDateLabel.text = [item pubDate];
    cell.creatorLabel.text = [item creator];
    [[cell thumbImage] setImage:[item thumbnail]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It looks okay. Can you post how you add items to it?

Comment: i think you should show more code

Comment: the array is allocated only when you init the viewcontroller, so likely only once. plz add the code where you insert items into the array

Comment: init method is called only once, when u create your viewcontroller(or whatever u have there), so, if u don't kill your viewcontroller by (popViewcontroller), your array is still alive.

Comment: init in ios? I guess it should be in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: I have added more code as asked by you people.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya MutableaArray is in a separate file that is inheriting from NSObject. That file has no ViewDidLoad

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Nope, init is fine, what if you don't have a view controller? Check out some of my code, I tend to use `init` exclusively. That's what it is there for.

Comment: @H2CO3 i guess the MutableArray discussion is over. I have edited and updated the data source, may be there is something wrong there that its not inserting more rows.

Comment: @Jessica I was referring to something else.

Comment: @yinkou i have added more code

Comment: @AndreyChernukha more code added

Comment: Your `items` is a property, of some class whose object is `channelFeed`. Are you sure `[[channelFeed items] count];` contains positive value?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya yes i am sure, in fact the very first time, it shows items in the tableview. But when i scroll down to the bottom of tableview, the delegate method finds that its the end of the tableview, it fetches more data from the feed and shows in the tableview. But it does not remember the already fetched data and only shows the items that it fetched in the last. I want the new items below the already fetched items

Comment: @Jessica: Can you send me the project? my mail id on my profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would initialize the array in a more convinient place. Apparently, your code calls the init, which will reinitialize the array and delete its contents.